# Relation between fragment and activity lifecycle

Tags: android-activity, fragment, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

I have an activity A , and there are 2 fragments associated with this activity, lets us call them F1 and F2. Now there is a fragment switch between these fragments, so in this case is the onResume() activity lifecycle event of activity A called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Activity's state will not change during a fragment transaction.

Comment: So if the activity was in onResume() state and after fragment switch there won't be a call to onResume() for activity again? Instead will it remain in onResume() as it was ?

Comment: Activity is independent from Fragment. Fragment's lifecycle depends on Activity's lifecycle.

Comment: So this means again onResume() won't be called ?